# Broken geometry displaying in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have one plane geometry on top of a box geometry, they are 10 pixels apart (not touching).
How it suppose to look
[image: How it suppose to look]

When I rotate my camera to a steeper angle, the front panel appears to be broken.
The black plane is broken
[image: The black plane is broken]

I tried on different machines but the problem persists. I am using Threejs WebGL 86.

Please help! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you use THREE.CanvasRenderer()?

Comment: Well, let's see your code!

Comment: Is transparent set to true for the plane face? Can you set up a jsfiddle to show your code and the resulting issue?

Comment: What's the distance of the camera's far plane?

Comment: Agreeing with @neeh. Please post how you set up your camera. If the distance between your near and far planes is too great, you could encounter depth precision errors, which can result in z-fighting like this.

Comment: Yes I used the Canvas Render! It solves when I switch to webGL render! Thanks@prisoner849 and thanks everyone who helped!!

Comment: @prisoner849 after I switched to webGLRender(), the texture quality gets lower. how do I boost up the texture quality? (I changed the black plane to an image)

Comment: well. it tells me that the texture is not power of 2

Comment: solved! @prisoner849